# How to find out if all enqueued files are uploaded?

Tags: uploads

I am using a script that identifies jpgs and pngs by their filename and adds them to various posts.

I would like to auto-run the script as soon as the last image of a bunch of files is uploaded (through the media upload panel).

How can I find out, if this is the case? (Preferably PHP, not JS.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/saving-media-which-hook-is-fired

Comment: Both answers mentioned in the link you posted, are workarounds. I would prefer a more generic solution, but I of course will accept an answer that says "there is no way of doing that."

Comment: I have never dealt much with the media uploader but if you read the answers to the other question you should notice that the the consensus is that there is no clean way to do this.

Comment: I did. Thanks anyway for your pointer to that thread!